# Missing '@end' // @end must appear in an objective-c context

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode4.5

This is my code:

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
   @interface CustomCellArticle: UITableViewCell
   @property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel *name;
   @end
```

In first time I received this error:

```
Missing @end
Expected identifier or '('
```

in the first of the code, and it required me to add @end in the first to fix it. 
the code became like this:

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
   @end //here the seconde error
   @interface CustomCellArticle: UITableViewCell
   @property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel *name;
   @end
```

When I add it, I received a new error:

```
@end must appear in an Objective-C context
```

I don't know what's happened exactly, please help! 
I used the same class in another project and it works fine!

Comment: do you have any other #import besides UIKit?

Comment: 2nd one is **DEFINITELY WRONG**

Comment: In the first one, you might have another @interface above displayed code....

Comment: Why would you at all assume or expect the second snippet to work? o.O

Comment: post the code after `@end` in first one. you might have missed @end after `@implemetation` i guess

Comment: Press cmd+A and then ctrl+I, then check all your statements are startign from boreder like all  four `@` must be below `#`... this is make sure you dont have an extra `{`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes that is from a another header or implementation file already imported beforehand that is missing a @end

It could be a .h or .m file

Comment: Yes it could also be a missing } bracket or similar in some other code. Just to be clear, this error is not in the code you have shared, it is in another class, some other code that is loaded when the application runs before that which you have shared.

Comment: Thanks, really helpful! :)

Answer (score 0):

@end should only come once in a single file.Whats with the top @end.And import all files at the top ?

Answer (score 0):

you may have opened a "{" that is never closed with a "}" before the @end line...

so, the error is not at the @end line... but xcode just find out you are missing a "}" or ")"

Answer (score -1):

Let me show whole file .h and .m file then i can answer well No Problem.

You need to remove first `@end` from .h file and run you will solve the issue.

Instead of this :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

@end

@interface CustomCellArticle: UITableViewCell

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *name;

@end

Use this :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

@interface CustomCellArticle: UITableViewCell
{

}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *name;

@end

May this will help you. This is working fine for me.

I have checked also in xcode. You Just need to remove first `@end`.

If this thing is not working you have some another issue.